# How to send data by jquery to serverside(asp.net)

Tags: jquery

I have to insert data of multiple rows of html table  into a database,Ii want to do that by using j query ,i think i have to convert whole data of html table into xml format, but i dont know how to do that or there is another way which is better than that

Please give me any advice on that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect your data in any way suitable for your server script (xml, json or just a number of key=>value pairs) and send it using standard ajax method. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://yourserver.com/you/script",
    data: data, // the data you collected and want to send to server
    dataType: (jQuery.browser.msie) ? 'text' : 'xml',  // data type you expecting as answer from server
    success: function_to_parse_returned_data  // function that will parse answer
}); 

function function_to_parse_returned_data(xmlData) {
    if ( typeof xmlData == 'string') {
         data = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
         data.async = false;
         data.loadXML(xmlData);
    } else {
         data = xmlData;
    }
    // do something with data
 }
```

Comment: thanks dimanoid for your answer,but i dont know how to convert the data of table row into xml by j query

Comment: then i need some example from you of that table

Comment: i am converting the table into xml but i get error when i send this xml to server side..